# go get with source.cloud.google.com

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I have a project that is hosted on source.cloud.google.com. I am hoping to use `go get` and go modules to manage it. When I do `go get`, I get the following:

```
$ go get source.cloud.google.com/<PROJECT-ID>/<REPO>

go get source.cloud.google.com/<PROJECT-ID>/<REPO>: unrecognized import path "source.cloud.google.com/<PROJECT-ID>/<REPO>" (parse https://source.cloud.google.com/<PROJECT-ID>/<REPO>?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about the **.git** in the end

```
go get source.developers.google.com/p/<PROJECT-ID>/r/<REPO>.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a [vanity URL](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/govanityurls).

vanity.yaml

```
cat vanity.yaml
paths:
  /<REPO>:
    repo: https://source.developers.google.com/p/<PROJECT-ID>/r/<REPO>
    vcs: git
```

Comment: Hmmm I don't know how this can work with Docker? can you tell me how to manage such case?