# Go Get for Google's Cloud Source Repository

Tags: go, gcloud, google-cloud-source-repos, google-source-repositories, go-get

Making two different `go` modules

1. `source.cloud.google.com/me/a`
2. `source.cloud.google.com/me/b`

With `source.cloud.google.com/me/common` as a common lib dependency (to share a model)

I'm trying to `go get source.cloud.google.com/me/common` (even manually wrote it in the `go.mod` file) but I keep receiving the following error:

```
package source.cloud.google.com/me/common: 
unrecognized import path "source.cloud.google.com/me/common" 
(parse https://source.cloud.google.com/me/common?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

I have `gcloud` set up to be able to use `app deploy` and create new source repositories. I've tried setting up `ssh` for google cloud and attempted to use manual credentials. This neither works locally or in the google cloud build service.

**I want to do two things:**

1. Be able to `go get` this dependenc`source.cloud.google.com/me/common`
2. Be able to integrate this `go get` into my App Engine automated build pipeline.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jared Hooper i need help for same, it would really helpful if you can share how you have solved this  problem ?

Comment: any workaround? I am stuck..

Comment: This dev is using vanity URLs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687342/go-get-with-source-cloud-google-com/53694868#53694868 PS: @Emixam23 yes, I saw you there ;-)

Comment: But I still don't really understand tbh :/

Answer (score 2):

1. Configure repo on https://source.cloud.google.com/
2. Authorize manual git access https://source.developers.google.com/p/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/r/YOUR_REPO
   In this example: https://source.developers.google.com/p/m/r/common
3. Your `common` module should go like `source.developers.google.com/p/m/r/common.git`
4. Run: `go get source.developers.google.com/p/m/r/common.git` on the other module

Comment: What is `Authorize manual git access`? Is that a setting? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following steps:

1. Make sure it has manual git access - You can try a git clone from folder "a" to check if correct git access is in place. Delete it after it gets cloned.
2. Make sure that you are using HTTPs - looks like you are good in that regards - go1.14 made HTTPs as default for go get's.
3. Now, coming to the actual problem - looks like your private version control systems isn't sending the required "go-import" meta tag.

For example - refer any github go module, you can see the "go-import" meta tag:
[image: Zap module for logging]

In order to fix it, the VCS server needs to respond with this tag when `go get` tries to download "common" module

```
<meta name="go-import" content="source.cloud.google.com/me/common git https:source.cloud.google.com/me/common">
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:
`got get source.developers.google.com/p/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/r/YOUR_REPO.git`